# Pseudonorm from royden book

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

How to show the triangle in equality for the following norm $\|x\|=inf_{y\in Y}\|x-y\| $, such that $X$ is a normed linear space and $Y$ is a closed linear subspace of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
\inf_{y \in Y} (\|x_1 - y\| + \|x_2-y\|) \leq \inf_{y \in Y} \|x_1 - y\| + \inf_{y \in Y} \|x_2 - y\|
$$
since
$$
\{\|x_1 - y\| + \|x_2-y\| : y \in Y\} \subset
\{\|x_1 - y_1\| + \|x_2-y_2\| : y_1 \in Y \text{ and } y_2 \in Y\}
$$

Comment: can you be a bit precise
?

Comment: @dyyyyssss okay: I meant that $x_1,x_2$ are arbitrary elements of $X$.  Now my answer is completely unambiguous, so it is completely "precise".  I don't think that's what you meant to ask, though.

Comment: @dyyyyssss I **think** you wanted to ask something like "what does this have to do with my proof?" or "why does the first statement follow from the second?".  I'm not a mind reader, so you'll have to be more precise with your questions.

Comment: I follow your two statements above. you somehow need to show that infy∈Y∥x1+x2-y∥≤infy∈Y(∥x1−y∥+∥x2−y∥)≤infy∈Y∥x1−y∥+infy∈Y∥x2−y∥
. So the first chain of this inequality is not obvious. What do you think?

Comment: The first part seems the most obvious: since $\|x_1 + x_2 - y\| \leq \|x_1 - y\| + \|x_2 - y\|$ for every $y$, it must be that
$$\inf_y\|x_1 + x_2 - y\| \leq \inf_y(\|x_1 - y\| + \|x_2 - y\|)$$